# Run local Selenium Tests via Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, automated-tests

I would like to run local Selenium test script written in Java, via Jenkins/Hudson. Is it possible to run scripts from my local windows machine? So far I have written some simple Selenium tests in Java, which run perfectly if I execute them via Eclipse IDE. I would be thankful for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Local machine - Windows?Linux? You want run your test on Jenkins?

Comment: on a windows maschine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Selenium test in Java: assuming them  to be laid out as unit tests (junit or testng), second assumption is that project is governed by either ant or maven, so there is some test (or rather integration-test) target or phase being present and be running smoothly when invoked from IDE.
2. When such tests are launched, they hit to a running selenium server (remote-control) which in turn launch a browser and runs its magic. Here are options: selenium server might be running in background (and be always available), or it might be started right before that testing and shut down afterwards. The latter is a common case for maven: pre-integration-test phase is configured to launch selenium rc, (then integration-test phase runs the tests against it), post-integration-test shuts selenium rc down.

So up to this moment we might want to learn what targets (ant) or phases(goals) your IDE invokes when it launches your tests successfully (also, what variables it sets or what profiles it enables).

If you invoke the same command from cmd (like 'mvn clean integration-test') and it runs successfully (same as IDE), then just instruct jenkins to run the same goals/targets (I assume that jenkins is running on the same machine, at the same user session).

If cmd doesn't do the trick (and you've looked quite well into what IDE does for you when it launches your tests), then I'd asked for more details.

So, involved participants are: 0. ant/maven that run your junit tests 1. selenium rc that should be running in bg or launched by ant/maven first 2. browser (path to browser executable) 3. jenkins (which was assumed to be running in the same environment).

If any of the assumptions are false, please come up with more details of your setup.